# Windows NAS backup/restore solution with browsable filesystem

Tags: windows-7, backup, nas

I have been backing up my Mac to a NAS on my home network with Time Machine for years and now I'm investigating doing the same with a Windows system. My only gripe with Time Machine is that if I want to copy a file from the NAS to another PC, I must first restore the entire backup to my Mac.

I've been looking, but I can't discern whether or not the built-in backup functionality for Windows produces a collection of files I can browse and copy to another computer or if it saves a kind of image of the system the way Time Machine does. Can files backed up using the built-in Windows software be browsed and copied individually from my NAS to a second computer? If not, is there a software solution that makes this possible?

Comment: Backup systems value a few things, among these are versioning, and backup archive size. Compression is nearly always more effective when done across the entire archive rather than across individual files. What you need is a backup system with a cross-platform client that will allow this function.

Answer (score 0):

File History in Windows 10 provides "browsable" backups of your files.

Many third party backup solutions provide the same capability.